Compiling and loading on esp32-s3 assembler code
Im trying to compile and load on esp32 simple assembler code:
pin15.S
  
    .section .text  
    .global \_start

    _start:
     
        movi a2, 0x3FF44000  
        movi a3, 1 << 15
        s32i a3, a2, 0x4      # Set output bit for GPIO 15
    
    loop:
        movi a2, 0x3FF44000  
        movi a3, 1 << 15      
        s32i a3, a2, 0x4      
     
        call0 delay
     
     
        movi a2, 0x3FF44000   # GPIO base address
        movi a3, 1 << 15      # Mask for GPIO 15
        s32i a3, a2, 0x8      # Clear output bit for GPIO 15
     
        call0 delay
     
     
        j loop
     
    delay:
        movi a1, 0x3FFFFF
    delay_loop:
        addi a1, a1, -1      
        bnez a1, delay_loop  
        ret                  


i compile it with:
    xtensa-esp32s3-elf-as -o pin15.o pin15.S
    xtensa-esp32s3-elf-ld -T linkerscript2.ld -o pin15.elf pin15.o
where linkerscript2.ld
ENTRY(\_start)

    MEMORY
    {
    iram0_0_seg : ORIGIN = 0x40100000, LENGTH = 0x20000  /* Instruction RAM */
    dram0_0_seg : ORIGIN = 0x3FFB0000, LENGTH = 0x20000  /* Data RAM */
    }
    
    SECTIONS
    {
    .literal : {
        *(.literal)
    } > iram0_0_seg
    
    .text : {
        *(.text)
        *(.text.*)
    } > iram0_0_seg
    
    .data : {
        *(.data)
        *(.data.*)
    } > dram0_0_seg
    
    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
        *(.bss.*)
    } > dram0_0_seg
    }


Then add proper header:
esptool.py --chip esp32s3 elf2image pin15.elf  ` `

Then write to esp32-s3:
    esptool.py --chip esp32-s3 --port /dev/ttyACM0 --baud 115200 write_flash 0x10000 pin15.bin
On /dev/ttyACM0 i get:
    ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327

     Build:Mar 27 2021
rst:0x3 (RTC_SW_SYS_RST),boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
     Saved PC:0x403cdd11
     SPIWP:0xee
     mode:DIO, clock div:1
     load:0x3fce3810,len:0x1798
     load:0x403c9700,len:0x4
     load:0x403c9704,len:0xcbc
     load:0x403cc700,len:0x2d98
     entry 0x403c9914
     I (31) boot: ESP-IDF v5.2-dirty 2nd stage bootloader
     I (31) boot: compile time Aug 5 2024 03:46:49
     I (31) boot: Multicore bootloader
     I (35) boot: chip revision: v0.2
     I (38) boot.esp32s3: Boot SPI Speed : 80MHz
     I (43) boot.esp32s3: SPI Mode : DIO
     I (48) boot.esp32s3: SPI Flash Size : 2MB
     I (53) boot: Enabling RNG early entropy source...
     I (58) boot: Partition Table:
     I (62) boot: ## Label Usage Type ST Offset Length
     I (69) boot: 0 nvs WiFi data 01 02 00009000 00005000
     I (76) boot: 1 otadata OTA data 01 00 0000e000 00002000
     I (84) boot: 2 app0 factory app 00 00 00010000 00140000
     I (91) boot: 3 spiffs Unknown data 01 82 00150000 000a0000
     I (99) boot: End of partition table
     I (103) boot: Defaulting to factory image
     I (108) esp_image: segment 0: paddr=00010020 vaddr=40080000 size=00044h (    68) load  
  
     E (116) esp_image: Segment 0 0x40080000-0x40080044 invalid: bad load address range
     E (124) boot: Factory app partition is not bootable
     E (130) boot: No bootable app partitions in the partition table

Im trying to understand where is problem. Maybe i should prepare another partition table an write it


Im trying to understand where is problem

According to the esp32-s3 memory map from the TRM neither 0x40100000 nor 0x3ffb0000 map to the IRAM or DRAM:

On the other hand on the esp32 0x3ffb0000 does map to DRAM (but 0x40100000 still doesn't map to IRAM):

So I'd suggest to begin with aligning the addresses used in the linker script with the actual hardware. I think it should look like this for the esp32-s3:
    MEMORY
    {
    iram0_0_seg : ORIGIN = 0x40370000, LENGTH = 0x70000  /* Instruction RAM */
    dram0_0_seg : ORIGIN = 0x3FC88000, LENGTH = 0x78000  /* Data RAM */
    }

